# ECMA-334 (C# Language Specification) v. 5.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

Does anyone know when the 5th version of ECMA-334 (C# Language Specification) will be available?

I guess they are updating the standard for the <s>upcoming</s> C# version 4.0.

Comment: My educated guess is around the time frame of C# 5 :-)

Comment: Nobody replied so I guess I should contact MS directly :)

Comment: I think the question is up for closing as only having temporal significance...

Comment: You can find it in: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334-arch.htm. it is 5th edition (September 2017)